# Date is not converting from double milliseconds

Tags: android

How to convert double to date?

```
"orderDate":1538398507000,
```

this is how I'm getting date, and I'm converting it to date

```
Date d = new Date(myOrderDataList.get(position).getOrderDate()*1000);
```

but it shows 1970 as a year

Comment: why are you multiplying by 1000

Comment: Why double? Date it's long.

Comment: from backend they are using double as data type for orderDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this

```
private String getStringDate(long time) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString();
    return date;
}
```

Comment: got output as 01-01-1970

Comment: @khimji your numer return in my case Mon Oct 01 14:55:07 CEST 2018, so method is right. Let share some code for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `double` represents the number of seconds of you date from now, and the `Date` constructor in Java is expecting a number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970, you have to multiply your number to get a number of milliseconds (`* 1000`) and substract that from the current number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970 (`System.currentTimeMillis()`):

```
double myDouble = -242528463.775282;
long myLong = System.currentTimeMillis() + ((long) (myDouble * 1000));
System.out.println(myLong);

Date itemDate = new Date(myLong);
String myDateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(itemDate);
System.out.println(myDateStr);
```

But, the problem with the way you store your dates is that if you are calling this code today and tomorrow it will not return the same date, as the current time is changing. You should use `timeIntervalSince1970` instead of `timeIntervalSinceNow`.